# Highland.js and buffer(or queue)

Tags: node.js, reactive-programming, highland.js

So, I have a code bellow to model the issue:

```
const H = require('highland');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

let i = 0
const stream = H(function(push, next) {
  console.log('read', i)
  push(null, i)
  i++;
  Promise.delay(100).then(() => next())
})


stream
  .flatMap(function(x) {
    console.log('start writing', x)
    return H(Promise.delay(2000, 'y').tap(() => console.log('finish writing', x)))
  })
  .done()
```

which produces output like this:

```
read 0
start writing 0
finish writing 0
read 1
start writing 1
```

the problem: I want to have a buffer of some size where I will stack the data from producer. So, with the buffer of size 1, output should look like:

```
read 0
start writing 0
read 1
finish writing 0
start writing 1
read 2
```

so, I want to buffer value from producer if the "producer" is "busy". Is it possible to do such thing with highland?

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible (not by promises, however yes - with callbacks) and they did state that in [this longish issue thread](https://github.com/caolan/highland/issues/290)

One of the reasons why I decided to write [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet).

A simple case like yours:

```
let i = 0;
const stream = new (require("scramjet").DataStream)({read() { this.push(i++); })

stream.map(
    (x) => Promise.delay(2000, 'y').tap(() => console.log('finish writing', x))
).accumulate(
    () => 0
).then(
    () => console.log("done")
)
```

It just works as you want it. :)

Comment: please check my answer. What do you think?

Comment: Hmm... Well I just guess that scramjet would make that much much simpler...

If I understand you right [this single file](https://gist.github.com/MichalCz/435bc2085264556c2f746efe4e02b066) would do about the same what you wrote in your Gist...

And that is barely using any dependencies, while looking much cleaner in code... and quite surely this is much faster.

Comment: this library mute the errors somehow. Instead of a  normal error I see something short: 
`(node:97642) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 14): TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: >If I understand you right this single file would do about the same what you wrote in your Gist.

no, it doesn't work at all. There is one syntax error.
But i tried to adopt it(why don't you use functions from simulator?). https://gist.github.com/kharandziuk/f90cf6c44dbfcf23bbf569587c55685c – what am I doing wrong?

>and quite surely this is much faster.  
fix it and we will test. But I'll be pretty exited if the library is faster then standard library of node

Comment: Yeah. We're working on better error handling, but there must be some kind of error in one of the methods (in essence there's no object passed somewhere) - I'm sorry, but debugging is still a little tiresome...

As to the "no, it doesn't" this was just an example, how to crawl some API, so you'd need to adapt it to your needs (for example use the simulator, which I didn't look much into).

Comment: Ok. I've updated to use your API - [take a look at this](https://gist.github.com/MichalCz/ae37100f433c3dbf87cd00ad06689a30). This is twice as fast as highland and on real API's it'll be even quicker. What did you mean about the "standard library of node"

Comment: Now it looks like a reasonable discussion:) Thanks, for the sample. But it still doesn't work. You never call the insert function. To check it run the command with `DEBUG=* node your-sample.js`

and compare it with the output of https://gist.github.com/kharandziuk/e823707bf71fba9a4cdf944216773f58#file-crawler-js

also, now you should see that you have much the same amount of code.

Comment: Ok. So I got it going, but due to the fact that I'm not sure what does the "group by time or count" thing does, I can't get a consistent result with Higland. I updated the gist so now it works fully.

We'll look into that - maybe such a method would be good in Scramjet too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in [my arcticle](https://gist.github.com/kharandziuk/e823707bf71fba9a4cdf944216773f58)

The idea here – buffering is a part of stream api. Highland just manipulate streams